# Simultaneous threads only one seems to function at a time?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, generic-handler

Threads **a** + **b**, (both are trying to delete files).
**a** gets called first, then **b** while **a** is still running.
**b** deletes the file successfully but **a** doesn't.

If I run **a** on its own, **a**'s file deletes fine.

When I step through the code I can see that **a**'s MultiAttemptFilename gets overwritten with **b**'s.

I don't understand.

I have an ajax call pointing to a generic handler which passes the filename along with it.
In my handler I have the following code:

```
    Dim Dc As New Document
    Dim MyThread As New Thread(AddressOf Dc.DeleteFileMulitAttempt)
    Dc.MulitAttemptFilename = Filename
    MyThread.Start()
```

From my 'Document' class I'm calling the following:

```
    #Region "Delete"

  Public MulitAttemptFilename As String = ""
  Public Sub DeleteFileMulitAttempt()
      Dim TimeBetweenAttempts As Integer = 2000
      Dim NumberOfAttempts As Integer = 60
      Dim AttemptNumber As Integer = 0
      Dim Success As Boolean = False
      While (AttemptNumber < NumberOfAttempts)
          Try
              Success = (DeleteFile(MulitAttemptFilename) = "Ok")
          Catch ex As Exception
              Success = False
          End Try
          If (Success) Then Exit While
          Thread.Sleep(TimeBetweenAttempts)
          AttemptNumber += 1
      End While
      End If
  End Sub

...
```

This is to handle cancelled/failed uploads as they don't always delete right away (server locks etc), hence the loop.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might be missing the fundamental concept of multi-threaded concurrency. There are books dedicated to this, and often sections of .NET books will address this issue. Here's just [one article by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx) on the topic.

One short answer is you need to use VB's "lock" keyword. You create an object and you do roughly something like

```
lock(yourLockObject)
{
   //any code that might access a shared resource like the variable 
   //MulitAttempFilename [sic] would go here. 
}
```

I don't speak VB but it looks like you're making the one thing that really needs to be protected a global variable. Global data is pretty much a bad idea in any form and when it comes to multi-threading it's a really, really bad idea. You'll have to rewrite your code to protect access to the name of the file being deleted.  While you're reading up on multi-threading you might also want to learn about thread pools.

Comment: Thanks Tod. I was playing around with Synclock but having read that article I think I'm going to sideline this until I have more time to properly read up on threading. Cheers